# HDInsight - use more than 1 storage?

Tags: bigdata, azure-hdinsight

It's possible to associate multiples account storages to the same HDInsight cluster? How can I do that?

If it is not possible, how can I upload more than 200TB of information and process it with HDInsight?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The latest HDInsight supports multiple Windows Azure storage account during the provision process.  There are several ways:

- use the custom create option from the management portal
- use Windows Azure HDInsight PowerShell
- use the HDInsight command-line interface
- use the HDInsight .NET API

Answer (score 0):

You must add a new entry for each storage account to the C:\apps\dist\hadoop-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT\conf\core-site.xml files to be able to access the files in the container from HDInsight:

See http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/howto-blob-store/

Thanks

Allan